# What is the word for randomly drawing winners of a competition?

Tags: word-usage

Consider this scenario: a TV program asks viewers a questions and tells them to send the answer to them. Then the TV program, in a ceremony, will choose randomly 20 winners from those who sent it the correct answer.

What is the word for what happens in that ceremony? What is the word for randomly drawing winners of a competition?
And What is the word for such TV programs? Can we call them TV competitions?

Comment: The noun for what happens is *The **draw** will be conducted on live TV.* Alternatively, the process could be described by saying *Winners will be chosen/drawn/selected **by lot** on next week's show.* Imho, the "generic" term for such stuff is "Trash TV".

Comment: *to draw* can mean *to choose* in you are looking for a verb

Comment: Thank you both. I am looking for a word that can go on a list of TV programs, for example: 7pm. Drawing ceremony of Competition x. Or something that can be written on top of the TV screen when the ceremony happens.

Comment: To make it clearer, it's often called a *prize draw* (at least in the UK) rather than just a *draw*.

Comment: @legatrix Prize draw seems to be close to what I am looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What's going on here is an example of a "raffle". In this scenario, the prize is "raffled off". One might generically call this a "game show".